# How to use multiple archive templates for a taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, page-template, archives, template-hierarchy

I have created a custom post type (product) with a taxonomy (brand). I need to have the basic archive pages (type A) and then custom ones (type B) to create a product comparison page which esentially lists all the brands with links to an archive. This archive will list all the products from the brand, echo out content from custom fields etc.

There is two problem:

1. I can't tell wordpress when two use type A archive page and when to use type B archive page
2. I can't generate links to type B archive page

So how do I create two kind of archive pages with unique links? I'd like a url like this: sitename.com/compare/brand. I was thinking to store brand slugs in $_GET superglobals somehow to tell the page what I want to query.

What I normally would do is to make query all the taxonomy terms  want to list and echo them out in a list like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href='link to type B archive page'>Brand name</a></li>
...
</ul>
```

and then check somehow what brand does the page belong to and get all the posts belonging to that brand.

How do I do this?

Comment: After the edition, my answer is not valid anymore. I've deleted it.